# Responsive Banner HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a banner for a webpage. I wanted create a container that only look up 20% of the page height-wise and then the image within it would take up 100% on the container. However, the image just ends up taking up all of the page and not responding to % changes.

Html code:

```
<div class="banner">
<img src="img/header.jpg">
  </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}


.banner img {
  height : 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

if you dont want to use a floating banner, you might consider to change your styling as this:

```
.banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
}
```

vh = view height. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp.

and if you want floating banner to follow as your page scroll, use this:

```
.banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  position:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vh` instead of `percentage` for banner.  `1vh` = `1%`

```css
.banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
}


.banner img {
  height : 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `<img>` tag you can set the image as the background of your container.

```
.banner{
background-image: url("/img/header.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.banner` is not taking the height 20% from css. The reason is it does not have a parent element having height set. So here I have added `height: 100%` to `html` and `body`. Try the below example.

```css
html,body{
  height: 100%;
}
.banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background: green;
  font-size: 0;
}


.banner img {
  height : 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/13/09/42/banner-1090835_960_720.jpg">
</div>
```